# Does a spectral theorem exist for linear operator pencils?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering if a version of the spectral theorem (the projection valued measure case) holds for linear pencils of the form
$$
A-\lambda B
$$
where $A,B$ are self-adjoint on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (and possibly unbounded) but $B$ is strictly positive? If so, is there a good reference on this? Note that under "nice" conditions, $B^{-1}A$ is self-adjoint on a weighted inner product (put factors $B^{1/2}$ in the inner product of $\mathcal{H}$ - this is straightforward to prove rigorously), so it may be the case that $B^{-1}A$ is usually studied instead. I was also wondering if there are natural conditions for $B^{-1}A$ to be essentially self-adjoint on $\mathcal{D}(B^{1/2})$ (with the weighted inner product)? Certainly $B$ or $A$ bounded suffices but what's the most general condition?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$, which is not the same as $B^{-1} A$ when they don't commute, but has better properties.

Comment: Ah, no I did mean $B^{-1}A$. However, I have since convinced myself that I missed a subtle point - it looks like this is symmetric w.r.t. the new Hilbert space, the domain of $B^{-1/2}$ but not necessarily self-adjoint. I've amended the question accordingly.